# How to improve this simple template rendering class?

Tags: c#, parsing, templates

I just wrote a simple class. All it does is takes a string of input like

> Hello **@name**, you look **@adjective** today!

And replaces the `@variables` with their values from a dictionary. For example, passing in `new Dictionary<string,object>{{"name","Ralph"},{"adjective","stunning"}}` would give:

> Hello Ralph, you look stunning today!

Here's the class:

```
class Template
{
    List<object> nodes = new List<object>();

    public Template(string content)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; ++i)
        {
            char ch = content[i];

            if (ch == '@')
            {
                var match = Regex.Match(content.Substring(i + 1), @"\w+");
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    nodes.Add(new Variable(match.Value));
                    i += match.Value.Length;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Expected variable name after @ symbol at character {0}", i));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nodes.Add(ch.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public string Render(Dictionary<string,object> dict)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in nodes)
        {
            if (item is Variable)
            {
                sb.Append(dict[((Variable)item).Name]);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(item);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    class Variable
    {
        public readonly string Name;
        public Variable(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good approach to such a problem? I want to do as much processing as possible in the constructor so that I can re-render the template over and over efficiently without reparsing it.

Right now I'm looping over the whole node list looking for variable nodes so that I can replace them. Maybe there's a way I can "skip" to those nodes? Would that help?

Also, I'm parsing it character by character, but then I use a regex (which I want to start at the next character, so i use .Substring to get the remainder of the string) to get a "chunk" of text. I'm not sure how else I might get the whole variable name w/out using a regex?

This class is about to get a lot more complicated, so I want to make sure I have the right approach before I go any further.

**My 2 concerns are:**

1. What's a nice way to pull out a chunk of text from the current position, and advance the counter? For example, extracting the variable name once I've determined that the next bit of text should in fact be a variable name.
2. How should I store the nodes (in this case, just Text and Variable nodes) such that I can *quickly* render the template over and over later?

Comment: Is text the only thing you will attempt to render with your templates? RegExes are not appropriate for branched structures.

Comment: @rook: Yes, if by "text" you mean "strings", but it'll be HTML... possibly JSON or XML in the future. To be clear, the *output* will be HTML, not the input.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
s = s.Replace("@name", name);
s = s.Replace("@Adjective", adjective);
```

Also, I would avoid throwing exceptions when parsing text. Since user strings can contain virtually anything, it's better to just try and handle unexpected data as intelligently as you can.

Comment: It won't just be simple variable substitutions down the road. I'm going to add things like for loops and such, regexes won't work. I don't think throwing an exception is too bad; if they've written the template wrong, they need to know about it. Either that, or it silently spits out nothing and they scratch their head why it isn't rendering correctly.

Comment: Sorry if I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. I've just done tons of stuff like this. If you want a simple parser helper class, check out my text parsing helper class (http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-text-parsing-helper-class).

Comment: I'm going to be using it to parse this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/34761 This class is just the beginning. You said yourself, in your article, that it's necessary to scan character-by-character ;)

Comment: @Ralph: Sounds like fun. Almost reminds me of a language interpreter I wrote. Anyway, if you don't have any code started, you might find my helper class useful.

Comment: Might... can't see anything in there that I'd use just yet. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll almost certainly want to use some sort of associative container for your nodes, might I recommend a `Dictionary<string, Node>` instead of the `List`?  Also, I see no way to currently set those nodes.  And you may as well go ahead and make nodes a class as well while you're at it.

As far as parsing char by char and then using a regex, yeah that's probably not ideal but writing a tokenizer/lexer isn't the simplest of tasks either.  Fix it when you need to!

Comment: Yeah, I've been dabbling with ANTLR but I haven't gotten the hang of it yet, not too fond of it. Might be overkill for what I want anyway. How would a `Dictionary<string,Node>` help? I'd still need to pull out the variable nodes, which would still be `O(n)`, and dictionaries aren't ordered are they? Nodes don't need to be set again after the template is parsed, just read and rendered.

Comment: No Dictionaries are not oredered, at least not in insert order. A dictionary is a good place to store keyvalues for lookup but not to store a list to process in order.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the template multiple times I would suggest parsing the template in 2 steps, first one splits the template in literal text and field objects and store these in a list, then for each time you need to render it just loop over the list and output any literal text directly and call through the dictionary for each field.

We did something similar with our own temlpate engine going from regex replace to a pre parsed list and increased performance about 20 times :D.

Your current code would be perfect to split the original string.

Example:

```
List<Node> nodes = var list = new List<node> {new node {Type=ntypes.literal,Value="Hello "}, new node{Type=ntypes.field,Value="Name"}};

Enum NodeType {
    field,
    literal
}
class Node {
    public enum NodeType;
    public string Value;
}
```

If you will use it only occationally you could still split it but then save the array in for eaxmple JSON or serialize it so that you could very easily recreate the list without having to use regex.

Also if the array contains elements with (type, value) you could add more intelligense to it over time, multiple different dictionaries or maybe simple functions like @@substring(@field, 10) that is then parsed and executed ;)

But for more complex situations, going for a real parser solution is better as with increasing complexity all simple solutions will get ungainly and sacrifice performance.

We finaly turned to an Antlr based parser and are currently looking at expression trees for the rendering phase.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I was trying to do. I'm glad it's a good approach then :) I'm going to try parsing it myself first... then I might try that C# parser generator... forget what it's called now.

Comment: For simple @fieldnames a handcoded splitter is good enough, the first one we used was written by a collegue of mine in 20 minutes ;) and was pretty similar to your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through EVERY character of your string you should just execute your RegEx against the whole string and return a collection of Matches.

Comment: Can't just find-and-replace. There will be more elements than just variables... it'll branch, so I need to process it linearly.